# javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Help me with regular expressions. I need to check the text on the hour and minute. That is the first case, the text can be from 0 to 12. In the second case, the text can be from 1 to 60.

this is my code:

```
var hourRegEx = /^([0-9]{2})$/; //You can fix this line of code?

$(document).ready(
  function(){
     $('form.form').submit(function(){ 
  if( $('input.hour').val().match(hourRegEx) ){
      return true;
  } 
  return false;
  });
});
```

In my case, the code says that, for example 52, too, the correct answer

Comment: Unless you live in some alternate reality, hours can only be 0 to 11.

Comment: I do not know much about regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with `parseInt` and numeric checking:

```
var hour = parseInt($('input.hour').val(), 10);
if((hour >= 0) && (hour <= 11)){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Zhasulan Yes, far, far faster. [See jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-regex).

Answer (score 3):

If what you are inherently doing is comparing numbers you really shouldn't use a regex

I would do this:

```
var numericRegEx = /^[0-9]+$/;  

$(document).ready(
  function(){
     $('form.form').submit(function(){  
        var hourVal = $('input.hour').val();
        if( hourVal.match(numericRegEx) && parseInt(hourVal) <= 11){
            return true;
        }   
        return false;
     });


});
```

This may be overly complicated; if I was doing this I would just use parseInt, but the original code would return false for values such as "11blah" so some regex functionality is still used to check the entire string is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `/^([0-9]|10|11|12)$/`. It's short enough, and very clear :)

Edit: or, if @Jamiec is right and you're mistaken about the numbers, `/^([0-9]|10|11)$/`

For minutes, use: `/^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9])$/`.

Edit 2: ah wait, 1 to 60. Use this:

```
/^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60)$/
```

and for hours 1-12, if you need it:

`/^([1-9]|10|11|12)$/` or `/^([1-9]|1[0-2])$/`

Answer (score 2):

Why not convert it to integer and use `<`? Regex is not a substitution for integer arithmetics.

Comment: If you think so I'll try to do it, I'm not very good at regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This:

`[1-9]|1[0-2]` will match the hour ( 1 .. 12 )

`[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60` will match the minutes ( 1 .. 60 )

if you want to match 0 .. 11 and 0 .. 59 do this

`[0-9]|1[0-1]` will match the hour ( 0 .. 11 )

`[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]` will match the minutes ( 0 .. 59 )

if you want to match 00 .. 11 and 00 .. 59 do this

`0[0-9]|10|11` will match the hour ( 00 .. 11 )

`[0-5][0-9]` will match the minutes ( 00 .. 59 )

Comment: Although this is technically correct (so I won't downvote), this code is horrible. As a dev manager I would fire anyone who used regexes to do numeric comparisons

Comment: :) I'm glad it didn't apply for a job with you then :). But please note that i presented differend types of expression to induce the idea that they can get extremely complicated even in simple cases. But generally speaking i do agree with you. You should only use regex to get a rough data from some input and do another validation in cod after that.

Answer (score 1):

The RegEx for testing a number between 0 and 12 would be along the lines of `^([0-9]|1[012])$` and for the minutes: `^[1-9]|[2-5][0-9]$`.

I wouldn't recommend it though. Personally, I'd use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) to get the value as a number. You can check it's a valid number because `parseInt` will return `NaN` if it isn't. Then you can do your range check.

```
var hourVal = parseInt($('input.hour').val(),10),
    minVal = parseInt($('input.minute').val(),10);

if(hourVal && hourVal >=0 and hourVal <= 12){
  // hour valid
}

if(minVal && minVal >=1 and minVal <= 60){
  // min valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should handle also cases where the user inputs 00-09:

```
/^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])$/
```

Comment: for 24-hours that would obviously be:

    /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-4])$/

Answer (score 1):

Using regex is not viable for this case. You should compare integer instead, because '1', '01', '001' are valid too.

i recommand this kind of snippet

```
val = parseInt($('input.hour').val());
if (val >= 0 && val <= 12)
    // is valid ...
```

Comment: To be fair, his original code would return false for values such as "12blah" whereas this will return true. Hence why in my answer there is still a regex to test that the entire string is an integer.

Comment: But 01 is also a form of time.